# anonymous access to jenkins workspaces

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins installed on CentOS release 6.3 and Jenkins 1.474. I am using Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy so that only users in specific AD groups are allowed to log in to Jenkins and view particular jobs.

However I am trying to give anonymous access to workspaces for jobs so I can do a wget and specify the http URL. This is so the hosts I am managing via Jenkins can get certain hosts.

I have added Anonymous to the Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy section and ticked workspaces but this isn't working. When doing a wget I can access forbidden and when I put the URL in to a browser, I am asked to login. I have also configured Anonymous to have access to the workspace on the job itself, but still get access forbidden.

Has anyone got any ideas as to why his is not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are using Jenkins version 1.475

We have the following enabled for anonymous access:
Overall:
   Read -> Enabled
Job:
   Read -> Enabled
   Workspace -> Enabled

This allows access to anonymous users to view the Dashboard and the Jobs and also to the workspace...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that but no luck - i hit the project workspace URL and it prompts me for a username and password. I set read and workspace enabled for anonymous access. I have worked around it. The only thing I can think of is if there is a bug with this security setting. I see there is a new version i might bump up to. I've said this was a correct answer as it most probably is the right way to go AND you have it working. Cheers - Oli

Comment: @Oli.. I couldn't find it on Jenkins. Did you have any luck with it?

Answer (score 3):

As of Jenkins ver. 1.609.1, the changes can be made under
`Configure Global Security` | `Configure Global Security` (or `htTps://<your jenkins host>/configureSecurity/`).

Similar to [sdmythos_gr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13086205/1845976) just set `Overall Read` and `Job Read` for `Anonymous`.

[image]